# AWS Credential Helper stopped working after OS update

Tags: git, http-status-code-403, aws-codecommit

I used to connect to a CodeCommit repo with a Role using the AWS Credential Helper. But after an update ran on my Mac, git started throwing `403` errors.

I can verify that the Role that is read by the Credential Helper is being set in the environment variables. I can also see that `.aws/config` and `.aws/credentials` are intact. My global `.gitconfig` is unchanged as well, with the appropriate lines for AWS Credential Helper in there:

```
[credential]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

I am not sure what else to check. Any ideas as to how to re-connect to the remote would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I ended up installing [git-remote-codecommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-git-remote-codecommit.html) and re-adding the remote using the GRC URL. Things started to work again even though I still don't know what caused the issue.